# Python - stream user logs from Django app with Celery - does it fit?

Tags: python, logging, google-bigquery, stream, celery

I have a Django application that serves up to dozens of users a day, getting thousands of requests (10K max).

I want to log each request to a BigQuery table.
A simple way to do it is using [BigQuery streaming API](https://cloud.google.com/bigquery/docs/streaming-data-into-bigquery#bigquery_table_insert_rows-python), specifically the `client.insert_rows_json` method which is pretty simple to use for a single row stream.

**Problem**: `client.insert_rows_json` throughput is not quite good and can take 0.5-1.5 seconds per request, which is very bad for my app performance.

**Solution**: running `client.insert_rows_json` method asynchronously using celery task. I can write a simple task:

```
@celery_app.task:
def stream_bq_row(table_id, log):
    client.insert_rows_json(table_id, [log])
```

which will take place ~10K times a day. This way my app will keep a good performance and i will be able to see logs pretty much immediately on BigQuery table.

**Question**

Does this solution make sense? Using Celery task ~10K times a day is reasonable? I'm not too familiar with Celery and i'm not sure its a good approach to let it handle such a load.

Comment: You can use Celery to run the tasks asynchronously according to your requirement. It is recommended to use Celery to run the jobs asynchronously as given in this [documentation](https://docs.celeryq.dev/en/latest/userguide/tasks.html#tips-and-best-practices). Let me know if that helps.

Comment: Hi shayms8, If my answer addressed your question, please consider accepting and upvoting it. If not, let me know so that I can improve my answer.Accepting an answer will help the community members with their research as well.

Answer (score 1):

If you don't care about potential loss of data, you're better off just writing non-blocking requests (https://github.com/kanishka-linux/vinanti).  That said, if these are truly logs, maybe you should use something like filebeat or rsyslog to ship the logs to bigquery?

Answer (score 0):

For your requirement, you can use [BigQuery Storage Write API](https://cloud.google.com/bigquery/docs/write-api) which gives better performance than Legacy Streaming API.  Storage Write API facilitates both streaming ingestion and batch loading in a single API. It can process a large amount of data in a single commit and also it guarantees exactly one delivery so there is no need to write any logic for de-duplication.

For implementation in python, you can check examples in this [documentation](https://cloud.google.com/python/docs/reference/bigquerystorage/latest/google.cloud.bigquery_storage_v1.services.big_query_write.BigQueryWriteClient).